# Sending reports to different puppet master than $server

Tags: linux, ssl, puppet, puppet-enterprise

There are two puppet masters. `pupmasterone.localdomain` and `pupmastertwo.localdomain`. `pupmastertwo` is fetching configuration from `pupmasterone` and sending its reports to `pupmasterone`. (This is normal behaviour)

If we change the report_server in pupmastertwo to report to itself, its throwing error.

puppet.conf (pupmastertwo)

```
[main]
report_server=pupmastertwo.localdomain
[agent]
server=pupmasterone.localdomain
```

Error:

```
Error: Could not send report: SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=unknown state: sslv3 alert certificate unknown
```

How to get this working?

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.